# Oracle Error in oci_parse()

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have the following error

> Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\JQueryMobileTest\submit.php on line 28

this is my code :

```
        <?php 
    $sql="UPDATE table1 SET updated_date =SYSDATE ,trx_status ='Submitted'  where TO_CHAR(trx_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') LIKE '%$search%' AND trx_status = 'Saved'";

        $res= oci_parse($link, $sql);
        oci_execute($res);
    ?>
```

i don't konw whats the problem ,, please any one can help me ?

Comment: Connection probably failed, the value of `$link` might be `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$link` is boolean, then most likely its value is `false`. This happens when connection to database failed. `oci_connect` returns `false` if an error happened. See [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) for more details.

You can find the error by calling `oci_error()`. Example from the documentation:

```
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```